# Angular component not changing template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In the project I'm working on there some components structured like this:

```
;(function () {
'use strict'
angular
  .module('a')
    .component('comp', {
      templateUrl: function (Config) {
        return Config.path + '/a/a.template.html'
      }
...
```

And every component had its own template file, but there were little to no difference beetween them so I created one template file to be used in all of them, but when I changed `a.template.html` to `b.template.html` only in some of the components the changes took place, and when I inspected the unchanged elements the HTML that was being used was from `a.template.html`. Why only some of the components being changed? (Also the components have the same hiarchy and are also really alike)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, turns out that my browser was storing the HTML in the cache, so what worked was to just clear the browser cache.